# SOAP1.1 vs SOAP1.2

Tags: web-services, soap

I have a server using jax-rpc framework hence uses SOAP1.1 encoding. I got a new client(third party) which is supposed to emit only SOAP1.2 encoded message. I would like to know what are things I need to take care of.

In other words, as per my understanding what really my question is: technical difference between SOAP1.1 and SOAP1.2 message.

PS: for some reason, I can't upgrade my server framework to use jax-ws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Refer the below Link

http://hadleynet.org/marc/whatsnew.html

And refer the below URLs also

[http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-tip-jaxwsrpc/index.html
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-tip-jaxwsrpc2/index.html](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-tip-jaxwsrpc2/index.html)